# C++ and Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos

In just about all books I read it mentions windows APIs(e.g. DirectX) when talking about C++ and game programming.

What APIs are for Mac when using C++ or what can be used for multi-platform development?

I want to create games using C++ and am currently on a Mac. I have no problem switching between Unix and Windows if it is needed.

What is recommended for C++ game development and will programming for mac be a drawback?

Or should I just go with C++ and OpenGL and use it for all platforms? :P

Comment: If you don't want to write code twice, OpenGL would be the way to go.

Comment: Which would be a good book to start with? The Red book or its updated Orange 8th edition?

Comment: @Helium3: the Red book is the OpenGL programming guide and the Orange book is about GL Shading Language. Red book is a good start.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: This looks orange to me http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Programming-Guide-Official-Learning/dp/0321773039/ref=dp_ob_title_bk  But yeah, I saw the shading book. Ill start with this one.Thanks

Comment: @Helium3 it's orangish-red I suppose in that pic. It's really just a bad picture, though.

Comment: I highly recommend learning Objective-C for Mac OS X development.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I have thanks, and continue to do so. but now I want more powerful games.

Comment: @Helium3 C++ isn't really "more powerful" as such, if that's what you mean. Use the language you're most comfortable. C++ does have some very nice features that Obj-C lacks, IMO, but the opposite is true as well. But whichever language you use, it sounds like OpenGL is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I would recommend [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) and OpenGL.  SFML is a more modern, C++ oriented, cross platform framework that allows you to write common code for window, keyboard and mouse handling.  You would then write the bulk of your game using OpenGL, which is cross platform anyway.</strike>

I am using SFML and OpenGL myself to target Mac OS X, Linux and Windows, primarily developing on Mac (I can triple boot into any of the three OSs to develop on them).

EDIT: I've had a change of heart on this as I am a bit spooked by the Mac support in SFML; I am now going to use Qt as it is better supported, provides better tools, better documentation and better examples.

Comment: Call me cynical, but I'm generally suspicious of anything advertised as "modern, C++ and object-oriented". In my experience you can have any two of those, but not all three. (In particular, there is nothing "modern" about OOP designs in C++)

Comment: You've taken my words out of context; I meant more modern than SDL and C++ instead of C.

Comment: I know, but they use the same words on the SFML website. My point is just that there's very little "Modern" about using OOP in C++. :) It was more a comment on SFML than on your post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenGL wich is cross platform, and use GLUT or SDL for handling input and windows and stuff or use just SDL. (I would go with mixing OpenGL and SDL and because its easier to manage input that way and is still cross platform. Unless your making a 2D game, then use SDL as SDL is for making 2D games).

Ohh and one addition thing about OpenGL on Mac is the header for OpenGL is a little different from most tutorials:

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
```

Don't spend hours on that like I did...

Oh, and if you plan to use glut:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used it a little for iPhone development.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a 2D game I would also recommend you try [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/); it's a fairly young library that has the same scope as SDL. It's pure C++ (as opposed to SDL which is just C) so development should be somewhat easier for you, if you like OOP.

It would also appear that SFML is significantly faster than SDL:
► http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43